# rewrite rule to convert php querystring to html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help me in writing correct `.htaccess` code to get the wanted result.

I have the following pages:

www.mydomain.com/?exam=/hp-certification/

www.mydomain.com/?exam=/cisco-certification/

www.mydomain.com/?exam=/oracle-exam-prep/

www.mydomain.com/?exam=/faq/

www.mydomain.com/?exam=/support/

And there are many more pages but you can notice that the fixed part is: www.mydomain.com/?exam=

Instead of using query string links, I want the following links to work as above pages:

www.mydomain.com/hp-certification/

www.mydomain.com/cisco-certification/

www.mydomain.com/oracle-exam-prep/

www.mydomain.com/faq/

www.mydomain.com/support/

and so on.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

your link should be like this `www.mydomain.com/?exam=hp-certification/` and the rewrite rule would like this in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /?exam=$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry but after adding the above code in htaccess file, when i try to visit http://www.example.com/hp-certification/         i am receiving the following error  Not Found

The requested URL /hp-certification/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /?exam=$1 [L]` try this one.

Also make sure your web servers (apache / nginx ) mod_rewrite is enabled and allowed. you can generate the rewrite rule and learn more about it here http://www.ipdistance.com/mod_rewrite.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the following rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} exam=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

**So what does the above do?**

First, it will take the query `exam=` as a condition, if this condition is met then it will grab any version of the variable using `(.+)`.

It will then rewrite the URL using 301 redirection to show `http://www.example.com/anything/`. The use of `%1` is to grab the variable from `exam=` and then we use `?` to stop the original query string from appearing on the end of the newly rewritten URL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.